# String conversion to sec min and hour

Tags: swift, time

i have a time string

```
 duration = "00:01:28"
```

i want to show like 28 sec ,1 min. how to get separate component as seconds,minute and hour.

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from:duration)
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let comp = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date!)
        let hour = comp.hour
        let minute = comp.minute
        let sec = comp.second
        print(sec)
        print(minute)
```

I tried this code but I got a nil in the print statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. Of course `sec` prints `nil` because you didn't specify the `second` component.

To print the requested string format I recommend `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
let duration = "00:01:28"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:duration)
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date!)
let componentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
componentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
componentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .short
componentsFormatter.string(from: components) // "1 min, 28 secs"
```